# How to Quit in Designed for Families

Tags: java, admob

I added my app to designed for families program in play store. Now I want to quit in this program.

My admob views before designed for families

2500 views / daily

Now

*8 views / daily.*

I am added

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
            .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
            .build();
```

Getting this error;
*W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3*

Waiting ur helps. I tried uncheck in play publish console. Google sending a mail with policy error when I do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue with a specific application in an App Store, and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact Google directly for issues related to your application and the store.